# PHP string to javascript can break the code - some character, i guess, is the issue?

Tags: php, javascript, string

I am passing a PHP string into onclick. This text comes from YouTube (a video description). In some cases the string breaks the code.

Characters \n \r ' and " are removed so it is not obvious what character is the cause.

```
echo "<span onclick='update_hits(\"".$id."\");vidtxt=\"".$desc6."\";openVideo(\"".$v."\",\"".$sn." : ".addslashes($title)."\",0)'><img src='".$apng."' border='0' />Play large</span>";
```

I have tried everything I can think of to solve the issue but have not succeeded.

```
$desc6=nl2br($desc6);
$desc6=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1f]/', '', $desc6);
$desc6=preg_replace('/\xc2[\x80-\x9f]/', '', $desc6);
$desc6=preg_replace('/[\x7f]/', '', $desc6);
$desc6=nl2br($desc6);
$desc6 = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $desc6); 
$desc6=preg_replace('~\p{C}+~u', '', $desc6);
$desc6=htmlspecialchars($desc6);
$desc6=preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $desc6); 
$desc6=ereg_replace('[[:cntrl:]]', '', $desc6); 
$desc6 = str_replace(chr(127), "", $desc6); 
$desc6=preg_replace('/\bKa(\W|$)/i', '', $desc6);
$desc6=addslashes($desc6);
```

Most description strings work fine, even those with text in other languages. But something breaks this sometimes.

Stripping to just ascii, which would mean that I cannot display non-english languages, does work.

```
$desc6=preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $desc6);
```

The following allows all descriptions to work, but languages like Korean don't appear properly:

```
$desc6 = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $desc6);
```

Any ideas?

ps:
    $desc6=json_encode($desc6);
breaks all :(

Comment: Do you even know what this is code does? I mean, you are doing some steps multiple times (e. g. `nl2br`, removing 0x7F).

Comment: They are filtering the UTF. I'll remove redundancy when I find the solution.

Comment: does your HTML page make sure its charset is UTF-8? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`? Also do you have an example string that breaks your code? Link to your application?

Comment: Example is the description to this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5RzCBBNgv4 On YouTube the description doesn't have some wierd symbols that I see (I get this text from gdata).

Comment: Yes, it is utf-8 in the header. Good idea though.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is two functions:

- [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) to encode the JavaScript strings.
- [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) to encode the HTML attribute values.

Both in action:

```
echo "<span onclick='".htmlspecialchars("update_hits(".json_encode($id).");vidtxt=".json_encode($desc6).";openVideo(".json_encode($v).",".json_encode($sn." : ".$title).",0)", ENT_QUOTES)."'><img src='".htmlspecialchars($apng, ENT_QUOTES)."' border='0' />Play large</span>";
```

Comment: Have tried this but it didn't help. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: This doesn't look right to me. There seems to ' and "s missing ?  I tried vidtxt=json_encode(\"".$fgh2."\");  but without success - all broken. Need ti add json script?

Comment: @SteveClarke Please try the example as I wrote it. It doesn’t need to be changed or adjusted in any way. It’s ready to be used as it is.

Comment: Also tried vidtxt=\"".json_encode($desc6)."\";  Doesn't work - breaks all.

Comment: The error is in $desc6 so I tried: $desc6=json_encode($desc6); first also. Same - so it is not your code but the json_encode() not working with the utf-8 strings

Comment: @SteveClarke Actually, `json_encode` does work with UTF-8 encoded strings *only*.

Comment: The strings display ok. but the odd one breaks the javascript somehow. The ones that give a problem are not the Korean ones but obstensibly in English - so there must be a dodgy character in those.

Comment: Gumbo - maybe need a second parameter for the json_encode() ?

Answer (score 0):

`.addslashes($title)."\",0)`
Shouldn't that be "\""